# Will 'Error creating temporary file transfer folder' in netbeans affect the working of my application?

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans, glassfish

I am working on a java web application using netbeans7. I get an exception every time I run my application.
The exception is: java.io.IOException: Error creating temporary file transfer folder.

I feel my code is running fine despite this. I wanted to know will it affect the application at any point of time and why is it a recurring exception? Is there any problem with my code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195384

Its a known Netbeans bug.